# CSS output on iphone different from PC

Tags: ios, css, iphone, browser

So, let me tell my problem directly to the point. I'm developing a website right now. And so I try to visit this website I'm developing on with my iphone. The problem is, I got some different output when I visit that site with my PC and when I visit it with my iphone. [This](http://tinypic.com/r/6pat0w/8) image is when I visit it with my PC's Chrome and the output is just the same with all other browser in my PC while [this](http://tinypic.com/r/mra05v/8) is when I visit it with my iphone's Safari and so the output is same too when I visit it with my iphone's Chrome . See the difference betwwem visit from iphone and from PC? Yep. I got that "space" above my navigation bar while visiting it with my iphone. So can anybody help me solve this problem? Thanks a lot in advance.

Btw this is my CSS and HTML

```css
body {
  background: rgb(25, 181, 254);
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1050px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
#logoBox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#logoBox:active {
  height: 140px;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
.logo {
  background: url('img/icon/logo.png') no-repeat;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
}
#navBox {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
.transition {
  transition: height 0.15s, margin 0.15s, background 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.15s, margin 0.15s, background 0.7s;
  -o-transition: height 0.15s, margin 0.15s, background 0.7s;
  -ms-transition: height 0.15s, margin 0.15s, background 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.15s, margin 0.15s, background 0.7s;
}
#navBox:active {
  height: 140px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#navBox.green {
  background: rgb(80, 190, 106);
}
#navBox.orange {
  background: rgb(250, 170, 30);
}
#navBox.green:hover {
  background: rgb(4, 160, 114);
}
#navBox.orange:hover {
  background: rgb(240, 130, 20);
}
#iconBox {
  height: 53.4%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 13.4%;
  text-align: center;
}
#iconBorder {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
img.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
a.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navProp {
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.3%;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 6.7%;
}
.center{
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Welcome to SIRIUS</title>
  <?php require_once "theme.php"; ?>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <a href="index.php" class="nav">
      <div id="logoBox" class="transition">
        <img src="img/icon/logo.png" class="logo">
      </div>
    </a>
    <!--
   
   -->
    <a href="index.php" class="nav">
      <div id="navBox" class="green transition">
        <div id="iconBox">
          <div id="iconBorder" class="center nav">
            <img src="img/x.gif" class="icon home">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="navProp">Home</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <!--
   
   -->
    <a href="aboutUs.php" class="nav">
      <div id="navBox" class="orange transition">
        <div id="iconBox">
          <div id="iconBorder" class="center nav">
            <img src="img/x.gif" class="icon aboutUs">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="navProp">About Us</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <!--

   -->
    <a href="register.php" class="nav">
      <div id="navBox" class="green transition">
        <div id="iconBox">
          <div id="iconBorder" class="center nav">
            <img src="img/x.gif" class="icon register">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="navProp">Register</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <!--
   
   -->
    <a href="login.php" class="nav">
      <div id="navBox" class="orange transition">
        <div id="iconBox">
          <div id="iconBorder" class="center nav">
            <img src="img/x.gif" class="icon login">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="navProp">Login</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <!--
   
   -->
    <a href="admin.php" class="nav">
      <div id="navBox" class="green transition">
        <div id="iconBox">
          <div id="iconBorder" class="center nav">
            <img src="img/x.gif" class="icon admin">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="navProp">Admin</div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies I cant see your images as work are blocking content :P

Im guessing here but most likely it would be something that is being specified by the browser, that you have not margins etc. Try using a reset.css file or maybe using debugging (F12) on a desktop and pretend to be a phone to debug. (I'm pretty sure in chrome you can specify a phone browser type to be, im assuming all modern browsers have emulation for mobile)

Or it could be min-width: 1050px;
If you are designing this for responsive design you might want to make some @media queries.

[edit] I also notice you have nothing specifying html. Perhaps the browser is adding some css against the html tag? `html {margin:0; padding:0;}`

Comment: I've tried emulate on PC before and nothing's strange. I emulate it with opera and chrome and both output normally like what I want. But then when I use the real device, that strange "space" came out. Also I've tried using reset css but still not working. Wish I could post image here directly but I can't. It tell me I need at least 10 reputation first. But thanks for trying to solve anyway :)

Comment: Will see if I can have a look when I get home. I will be able to see what you mean then.

Comment: So how is it? Have you take a look? Still trying to solve this but can't do it.